# SQL Query in Ruby: Only select the changes

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

Suppose I have a table (`PriceHistory`) like this, every time I change **anything** in the row, I will record the **whole** row again in the table.

```
id | buy_price | sell_price | change_date
 1 |         2 |          2 | 2012-06-22
 2 |         3 |          2 | 2012-06-20
 3 |         2 |          6 | 2012-06-15
 4 |         5 |          5 | 2012-06-15
 5 |         5 |          7 | 2012-06-15
 6 |         4 |          8 | 2012-06-12
```

I only care about the change of `BuyPrice`,  Is there a way to just select row 1, 2, 3, & 5?

Here is the Ruby code I come up with, but it does not only select the changed rows

```
PriceHistory.select("id, BuyPrice, change_date").
order("change_date DESC")
```

Both Ruby and SQL answers are fine.

Comment: How are you changing things? Inserting new rows, or altering old ones?

Comment: inserting a new row every time if either buy_price or sell_price is changed

Comment: Are you sure you don't want 1, 2, 3, 4, and 6? The only run where the `buy_price` doesn't change is from 4 to 5.

Comment: @muistooshort I think the rows are going from 6 to 1, not 1-6. So when 5 is added, the buy price changed (so return that). When 4 is added, buy price is same (so don't return)

Comment: @simchona: Yeah, that would make sense given the `change_date` order.

Comment: I think it should return row 1,2,3,5.  Maybe 6 as well because that's a change from null to 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@histories = PriceHistory.select("id, BuyPrice, change_date").order("change_date DESC")

(@histories.size - 1).times do |n|
  if @histories[n].buy_price != @histories[n+1].buy_price
    puts "changed from : " + @histories[n].id.to_s + " to: " + @histories[n+1].id.to_s
  end
end
```

Good luck!